# Trying to create a bar chart using Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovVAW.jpg) is the chart I want to replicate.
[The data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9RkZ.png) after Pivoting below.

My code is below:

```py
pivoted. Plot(kind='bar',
                         stacked=True, 
                         colormap='tab10', 
                         figsize=(10, 6))
 
plt.legend(loc="lower left", ncol=2)  
for n, x in enumerate([*pivoted.index.values]):
    for (proportion, y_loc) in zip(pivoted.loc[x],
                                    pivoted.loc[x].cumsum()):
                 
        plt.text(x=n - 0.17,
                  y=(y_loc - proportion) + (proportion / 2),
                  s=f'{np.round(proportion * 100, 1)}%', 
                  color="black",
                  fontsize=12,
                  fontweight="bold")
 
plt.show()
```

Please help me recreate the graph. If you need the dataset let me know as well.

Comment: its probably easier to do this with seaborn

Comment: Is it? There is no 100% stacked bar options in seaborn :(